# Convert PDF to a tree

Tags: javascript, json, pdf, tree

I am writing an application in which I need to inspect the tree structure of PDF documents, modify this tree structure, and write the result back to another PDF.

The inspection and modification cannot happen in a dedicated library (e.g., [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)), since it is already written in a format-independent way for JSON-structured trees.

**Ideally, what I need is a lossless conversion from PDF to any tree format (XML, JSON, ...) and back, in JavaScript or any other programming language, or as a command-line tool.**

What I considered so far:

1. Using [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json). This converts a PDF to a JSON file. Unfortunately, the other direction (JSON->PDF) is not supported.
2. One can create a JSON with the Base64-encoded binary content of the PDF. This is lossless and works in both directions, but I am losing the tree structure that I want to inspect. Therefore, this is not an option.

Can anyone recommend a library or program to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see why this is off topic. _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it_